# Wordpress function/plugin to count number of rows in mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have additionals table in my Wordpress database that contain a lists of companies, link, description, etc. I'm using this plugin (http://wpdatatables.com/) to render the table in WP and it works great.

One feature it doesn't have is a way to count of the number entries (rows) in the table. I'd like to get this count and display it in a page on wordpress. For example, count all the rows in table X and display here (with a shortcode or something else) so I could have "TABLE X has 1,912 companies".

I came across this as a way to get started, but not sure if it'll work for what I need and then I'm not sure how to actually get the result into a post/page.

```
<?php
$myvar = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company_table WHERE name=*");

if($myvar == 0)
{
// no rows, do whatever.
}
else
{
// at least 1 row, do something else.
}
?>
```

or this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name' );
echo  $wpdb->num_rows . 'Rows Found';
```

How can I get the row count and display it on a page from this point (or some other recommended started point)?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I made a plugin with a shortcode like this and can get it to appear in my page correct, but it's rendering the wrong number of rows. It's only showing 1 row, when it should be several hundred.

```
function row_count_shortcode() {
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inno_db' );
echo  $wpdb->num_rows . 'Rows Found';
}
add_shortcode( 'row_count', 'row_count_shortcode' );
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)?

Comment: Yes...I think I have it going now with a shortcode (need to update question), but it's returning 1 row instead of the actual number.

Comment: Try `$wpdb->get_var()` instead of `$wpdb->get_results()`. Edit: That wasn't super clear, but it should be `$num_rows = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inno_db');`

Comment: @Evilzebra This worked. Thank you. Can you post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `get_results()` to `get_var()`

```
$num_rows = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inno_db');
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use `num_rows()` will ALWAYS return 1 (assuming the SQL is valid) even if the count was zero, because your SQL result set from the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` query will always return a result set with one row.

You need to actually read the COUNT value from the result set or just do regular `SELECT * ...` (or better to actually `SELECT primary_key ...` on InnodDB table) and use `num_rows()`. Don't use both `COUNT()` and `num_rows()`.